# storing a variable's value in another variable and reassigning it to that variable inside a loop in python

Tags: python-2.7

This is a very simple thing I am trying to do and it even works in powershell if I write a seperate piece of code. But in my program here, it does not seem to work:

here is my code : http://ideone.com/vV5ZNS

```
x = list(str(raw_input("Please enter a string: ")))

y = x
z = []
i = 0
j = 1
k = -1
n = len(x)
while i<n:
    i = k + 1
    j = i + 1

    while j<n:
        x = y   #does not reassign the orignal string array to x.
        k = i
        while j<n:
            z.insert(i, x[i])
            if (x[i] == x[j]):
                j = j+1
            else:
                x[i] = x[j]
                x[j] = z[i]
                print (x)
                print "\n"
                j = j+1
                i = i+1
```

Comment: I have added a comment to clearly state the problem, and it has been answered bang on. Please clarify as to what I have missed out while asking, so that I don't make similar mistakes while asking questions in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to store the original input list in `y` so that you can restore the value of `x` partway through your program.

This is not currently working because `y = x` causes both x and y to refer to the same list. Modifying one will modify the other. Example:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = x
>>> y.append(4)
>>> print x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here, a change was made to `y`, and `x` was modified accordingly.

To preserve the original values of the array, you should make a copy of it. This is typically done by indexing the array with a blank slice, i.e. `x[:]`. Example:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = x[:]
>>> y.append(4)
>>> print x
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here, a change was made to `y`, and `x` was not modified. You can apply this technique to your code by slicing whenever you want to assign x to y, or vice versa.

```
x = list(str(raw_input("Please enter a string: ")))

y = x[:]

#later, within the while loop:
    while j<n:
        x = y[:]
```